# Can HC-06 be used as a Bluetooth server to which multiple devices can connect?

Tags: avr, bluetooth

Title sums it up. I want to use my AVR to be a bluetooth server for multiple Android devices. Is it possible? If iy is not what other method can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is a simple module used as simple bluetooth-serial bridge.

Comment: Is there another option other than HC-06?

Comment: There are plenty of options, you can google them. The question is what kind of services your server is to expose?

Comment: I googled for a while, but there was no specific info about "multiple connections". My goal is simple. Two or three Android devices will send only one byte. After that I will use that byte in AVR and send back a response byte. That is it for now.

Comment: For this purpose you might consider different bluetooth profiles, not necessarily persistent-connection based. Each "client" can connect, send it's byte, and then disconnect. Not simultaneously.

Comment: Well, you gave me an idea right now. I can do the last thing you said with HC-05. When I get my "byte" I will make module go into CMD mode and AT+DISC will disconnect it in order to allow a new connection.